# Anaconda does not register previously initialized environments

Tags: terminal, anaconda

I have created anaconda environments in my previous session but after creating a new session in my terminal it seems like anaconda forgot the names to my old environments... Can anyone tell me why this is?

I tried accessing my old environments by doing `conda activate qts1`, but it gave me this error:

> `EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: qts1`
>
> `` You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`. ``

When I listed `conda info --envs`  I get [image]

So my previously defined environments exist, but their names have all been deleted? How do I fix this so I can use my old environments?

Answer (score 0):

stupid question... forgot I installed miniconda and that was the problem... Specifically, previous environments were defined in anaconda, and not miniconda.

To access previously defined anaconda environments, just activate it through its path:`conda activate /Users/usr/opt/anaconda3/envs/qts1` for example